# Tomcat 7 as windows service not accessible from other systems

Tags: windows, windows-7, tomcat, tomcat7

I have downloaded Tomcat 7 zip for 32 bit windows 7 machine. I have unzipped the package and created the windows service using ..\bin\service.bat. But when i start the service from windows services.msc, i could NOT access by web application from other systems. It can be accessed from localhost.

But when i start the tomcat from command line using ..\bin\startup.bat i CAN access my web application from other systems.

I have added address="0.0.0.0" in ..\conf\server.xml of tomcat. But still the problem exists. Tried with adding exception in firewall too. But no luck.

OS: Windows 7 Professional

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Add the ..\bin\tomcat7.exe to the Windows exception list. Everything works fine.
1. To to Windows Start --> Control Panel
2. Open windows firewall
3. Click on "Allow a program or feature through windows firewall" in the left menu
4. Add tomcat7.exe to the exception list and click ok.
5. Restart tomcat and now you can access tomcat from other machines

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it did not help me. I am having the same issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/675827/unable-to-access-apache-tomcat-from-remote-machines Any ideas?